# JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to execute tests

Tags: java, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Junit 5 suite class:

```java
@Suite
@SelectClasses({
    AAATests.class,
    BBBTests.class
})
public class SanityTMTestsSuite5 {
}
```

I use this version:

```xml
<junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
```

surefire configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/SanityTMTestsSuite*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and another dependency outside the surefire definition:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I execute `mvn test`, I get

> org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID
> 'junit-platform-suite' failed to execute tests
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryResult
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryResult.withRetainedEngines(java.util.function.Predicate)'

Comment: There's most likely a JUnit 5 version conflict somewhere. ${junit-jupiter.version} should resolve to 5.9.1 but probably does not. Or you have other dependencies that lead to older versions of JUnit platform libraries being pulled in. Maybe your full maven.pom can shed some light on it.

Comment: Found the working configuration, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This configuration worked for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <junit.version>1.9.1</junit.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/SanityTMTestsSuite*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit4 engine and JUnit 4 API  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: JUnit Jupiter does definitely NOT depend on JUnit4 nor the vintage engine. Maybe your tests `AAATests` and `BBBTests` are JUnit 4 tests?